# Laravel relationship is not showing

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models.  One of them is `Sales` with the following attributes:

```
protected $visible = [
    'id',
    'client_id',
    'is_paid'
];

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id', 'id');
}
```

The second one is `Client`:

```
protected $visible = [
    'id',
    'name'
];

public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sales::class, 'client_id', 'id');
}
```

I am requesting the data in this way:

```
$getSalewithClient = Sales::where('id', "=", 1)->with(["client"])->get()->toArray
```

And getting only the data from sale:

```
{
    id: 1,
    client_id: 1,
    is_paid: null 
}
```

But the client information is missing, even the key is not listed.

I do not know why, because at first this was working and suddenly did stop working, I am desperate.

Comment: What are the tables structures?

Comment: 1) Both relationships have `'client_id', 'id'` as 2nd and 3rd parameters, that cannot be right.  As long as you are using conventional column names/relationships, those are not even necessary - leave them out to avoid messing things up. 2) [No need for the array in `with()` here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading); 3) Sounds like @tsaikoga's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `$visible`, the relationship attribute is hidden, you need to add it to `$visible` array:

```php
 protected $visible = [
    'id',
    'client_id',
    'is_paid',
    'client'  // add relationship name here
];
```

So that you can see the result with it.

Comment: OMG, this is the most stupid error that i ever had. The weirdest thing is that this worked and suddenly stopped working. I don't understand that. Anyway, thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0):

> `return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id', 'id');`

I think it should be

`return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'id', 'client_id');`

First parameter is the column on foreign table, second one is the column on current table.